# Unexpected behaviour of std::discrete_distribution

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, random, std

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (debug mode), which doesn't have an iterator-based constructor for `std::discrete_distribution`, so I am using a workaround. However, when using this workaround, it produces a runtime error if the last element is not greater than the first element in `weights`.

This error is not produced when using an initialisation list.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::discrete_distribution<> dist1 = { 10.f,11.f,5.f };

    std::cout << "!" << std::endl;

    std::vector<float> weights = { 10.f, 11.f, 5.f};

    std::size_t i(0);

    std::discrete_distribution<> dist2(weights.size(), weights.front(), weights.back(),
        [&weights, &i](double){
        auto w = weights[i];
        ++i;
        return w;
    });

    std::cout << "!!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> !
>
> invalid range for discrete_distribution

Adding any number greater than 10 onto the end of `weights` would stop the runtime error occurring.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 3rd constructor described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution), that is:

```
template< class UnaryOperation >
discrete_distribution( std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax,
                       UnaryOperation unary_op );
```

The proper initialization of `std::discrete_distribution` instance requires that

`delta * 2 = (xmax - xmin) > 0`.

Comment: @pighead10 is there something more that you need to have explained?

Comment: Right. So is there no way of avoiding this other than reordering the vector?

Comment: you can just specify xmin and xmax directly and pass them into discrete_distribution constructor, but you have to ensure also that weights constructed with your unary predicate will be correct

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot I was using .front() and .back() for the min and max when they aren't actually the minimum and maximum values! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For this workaround, your lambda isn't actually using xmin and xmax (or the result of fw) to calculate the weights, so don't worry about re-ordering your array. Just pass 0 and 1 (or any other values where xmin < xmax) and it will work.

```
std::discrete_distribution<> dist2(weights.size(), 0, 1,
    [&weights, &i](float){
    auto w = weights[i];
    ++i;
    return w;
});
```

example: http://ideone.com/351Jhg